# How to fix CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT in R?

Tags: ssl-certificate, jira-rest-api, rscript, trusted-sites

I'm using R 3.5.2 version.
And 1.4.0 version for httr package.

I calling an restApi Get:

```
CallingRestAPI = function(url){
  call.response <- GET(url = url, authenticate(username, password , type = "ntlm"))
  return(call.response)
}
```

Was working fine suddenly giving this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT
```

Answer (score 2):

Running this fixed it for me per [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/curl-problem-running-shiny-application-on-local-machine/36388):

```
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=0L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Update httr to the development version:

```
devtools::install_github('r-lib/httr')
```

or

```
remotes::install_github("r-lib/httr")
```

See:

- [Schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error
  CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/193)
- [Do not override the CA bundle](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/pull/603)
- [httr (development version)](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: httr version 1.4.1 fixed this bug